# How to add data that is not exist in database table?

Tags: php

In database table I have array field, than contains values `[1, 2, 3]`

How to insert this field new value from user request, where request is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So, I need to insert only `4` number, because the rest values are exist.

I tried to use:

```
$result = array_diff ($data["parameters"], $prototype["parameters"]);
```

Comment: it is possible not to insert the data to database table . you can over write as All Cricket Videos answered else if you want other than i can add my answere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just might be better to insert the replace the old array with new array if that is what you need instead of calculating the diff